# jQuery each() issue with multiple ul elements

Tags: jquery, each

Ok I have a dynamically created set of elements where each particular kind gets its own UL container for its set of data. So what I have is a 1-20 UL sets on my page at any given time and I am trying to do an $.each() on them. So I can run through them and double check to make sure there is greater than one li per UL. Cause in some cases my datasets are temporarily out and need to be refilled. So what I want to do is if the length of any given ul is <= 1 I want it to put a message in that container, no matches currently. Instead of leaving it blank. So

I try:

```
$.each('.service_container', function(){$(this).append('no data');});
```

and

```
$('.service_container').each(function(){$(this).append('no data');});
```

along with a half a dozen or more concepts for the function section of the each() to see if I can get it to do anything, and I can't.. so I am looking for suggestions.

Comment: Please show us a representative piece of the HTML for the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags so we can give complete answers.

Comment: When you say not working, are you looking at the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could do:

```
$('ul.service_container').each(function(){
  var $ul = $(this);
  if ($ul.children().length <= 1) {
    $ul.append('<li>no data</li>');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To just find the UL tags with no LI tags, you could do this:

```
$("ul").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("li").length <= 1) {
        // this UL tag has one or zero LI tags in it
        $(this).append('<li>no data</li>');
    }
})
```

Comment: I think you want to test <= 1.

Comment: @drewish - you are correct - I didn't see that fine point in the OP's question.  I've modified my code accordingly.